Martial arts movie from 70s or 80s - Series of hero / protagonist characters
It was a Chinese martial arts movie where there wasn't a primary protagonist. 
It would focus on a single fighter who you would think is the hero until they died, and they would essentially pass the baton to the next fighter/protagonist to continue the story. 
Each hero would have their own weapon and style of fighting. I remember one guy had these blades that came out from his elbow and another had sais. There was at least one female hero too.
